# How we can get value of double variable and save and set text at another activity?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to save latitude and longitude and display in another activity.
How can I get lat and lan from here and save and display in another activity?

Here is my code:

```
        ic_save_proceed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    try {
                        //code
                        double aLat = lat;
                        double aLan = lan;
                        String c = country;

                        String LebalStr = Lebal.getText().toString().trim();
                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "enter Lebal"+LebalStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if (LebalStr.isEmpty()) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "enter Lebal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(AddLocation.this, addActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("Lebal", LebalStr);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

> Activity One - Sending data from here

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityTwo.class);
intent.putExtra("lat", lat);
intent.putExtra("long", long);
startActivity(intent);
```

> Activity Two - Receiving data from ActivityOne

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
float lat = intent.getFloatExtra("lat");
float long = intent.getFloatExtra("long");
```

> Here you can display the lat long in textview. Thanks in advance.